# What is the difference between \write and \immediate\write?

Tags: write

What is the difference between `\write` and `\immediate\write` commands when writing to a text file?

`\write` command seems to write nothing on the text file...

Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\texttowrite

\newwrite\mytextfile
\immediate\openout\mytextfile=\jobname.txt

\newcommand*{\texttowrite}{Some text}

\begin{document}

\write\mytextfile{\texttowrite}
\immediate\write\mytextfile{\texttowrite}

\immediate\closeout\mytextfile
\end{document}
```

**EDIT (after egreg's answer and comment): one more exemple for beginners (like me) :**
I allow myself to share this small test which illustrates an aspect of the operation of `\write` and `\immediate\write`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newwrite\mytextfile
\immediate\openout\mytextfile=\jobname.txt
\newcommand*{\texttowrite}{Some text}
\begin{document}
\texttowrite

\write\mytextfile{\texttowrite 1}
\immediate\write\mytextfile{\texttowrite 2}
\write\mytextfile{\texttowrite 3}
\immediate\write\mytextfile{\texttowrite 4}

\closeout\mytextfile
\end{document}
```

Content of `\jobname.txt`:

[image]

Comment: immediate is written immediatly, without it the write happens when the page is shipped out. Your \write doesn't write as you closed the file to early with the \immediate\closeout.

Comment: @Ulrike Ok I understand your comment. After little tests it apears that if I replace `\immediate\closeout` by just `\closeout` the `\write` command "works". So I definitly don't understand what the `\immediate` command do...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main usage of `\write` is to record information such as page numbers when preparing a table of contents or for cross-references.

Thus `\write` stores the text (without macro expansion) and writes it (with macro expansion) after a page is shipped out.

In some cases, such delay is not needed or wanted, so you can prefix `\write` with `\immediate` and, in this case the `\write` operation (with macro expansion) is carried out immediately.

If you have a `\write` operation that happens to be executed *after* a file has been closed, the tokens will be shown on the terminal and, of course, not written out. This is your case: you close the output file before the last `\write` has a chance to be performed.

Even

```
\documentclass{article}

\newwrite\mytextfile
\immediate\openout\mytextfile=\jobname.txt

\begin{document}

\write\mytextfile{some text}

\end{document}
```

would write nothing on the specified file, because no page is shipped out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, the `\write` command is only "working" if there is no `\immediate\closeout` in the entire document? If yes, I don't understand the need of `\immediate\closeout` instead of `\closeout`... Do you think I should ask a question about `\closeout` and `\immediate\closeout` too?

Comment: @SylvainRigal Also `\closeout` follows the same rule as `\write`

Comment: I don't fully understand the need of `\immediate\closeout` instead of just `\closeout`, but it's another question... Thanks again!

Comment: @SylvainRigal In my last comment I said thay you *don't* want to do `\immediate\closeout`, but just `\closeout`.